# Textmate rails html indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate

When I end an erb tag in rails html (or an html tag for that matter) the end tag is always indented in with respect to the start tag. As in the lines below.

```
<% if condition %>
    <% end %>
```

Why wont the end tag indent correctly?

I also end up with:

```
<div>
    </div>
```

What am I missing?

The editor says HTML (Rails) in the bottom status bar.

Also why does textmate not auto end an html tag.
For example in Eclipse if you type `<div>` then as soon as you type another `</` it will automatically know that you need a `</div>`. Can Textmate not do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about your indentation problem, I don't remember TextMate doing that.

**EDIT:** Yes, it does that, I don't know how I accepted this behaviour for all these years and no idea how to change it.

About the second part of your question, TextMate has many ways to help typing HTML tags and all these ways are very easy to find simply by looking at its menus.

**EDIT:** I've added some clarification and a supplementary hint.

1. **The now ubiquitous snippet system with tab-completion:**

   Type `h1` then hit `Tab` to obtain a complete first-level header.

   It works for many (not all) HTML tags and is unbelievably helpful. Since it was introduced in textMate this system has been copied in many editors/IDEs.

   I think it will do indentation right most of the time.
2. **Insert open/close tag:**

   1. type `div`,
   2. select it with `Shift`+`Alt`+`Left`,
   3. hit `Ctrl`+`<`,
   4. obtain `<div></div>` with the cursor between the tags.

   It is smart enough to expand `br` to `<br>` but not enough to expand it to `<br />` in XHTML documents which has been an oooooold complaint.
3. **Insert close tag:**

   1. type `<body>`,
   2. hit `Alt`+`Cmd`+`.`,
   3. obtain `<body></body>` with the cursor between the tags.

   Which is more or less equivalent to the behaviour found in Eclipse.
4. **Wrap selection in open/close tag:**

   1. type `something`,
   2. select it with `Shift`+`Alt`+`Left`,
   3. hit `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`w`.
   4. obtain `<p>something</p>` with the first `p` selected
   5. replace `p` with `span`
   6. see how the second `p` is updated as you type?

   Bonus: you can safely add attributes as you type, these won't be mirrored in the close tag.

Hints:

- Suppose you are creating a form and are at `<form`, you can hit `Alt`+`Esc` to display a contextual menu with a bunch of possible completions.
- Snippets are easy to customize, hit `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Cmd`+`b` to open the Bundle editor. Have fun!

Comment: Ctrl+< does nothing whatever for me I'm afraid. Have I got something setup wrong? Ctrl+Shift+w seems to wrap stuff in <p></p> Alt_Cmd+. does work but the indentation is still wrong.